# Insert increment and decrement for quantity column value - DataGrid Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datagrid

Hello how are you? I would like your help. I'm building a DataGrid with Material UI and I got stuck in an increment and decrement deployment on a column.

What I would like to add to my QTDE column: https://npm.io/package/react-native-ui-stepper

Here is my column code:

```
columns: GridColDef[] = useMemo(() =>
        [
            {
                field: 'id',
                headerName: 'ID',
                width: 70

            },
            {
                field: 'nome',
                headerName: 'Estabelecimento',
                width: 180
            },

            {
                field: 'status',
                headerName: 'Status da entrega',
                width: 180,
                type: 'singleSelect',
                valueOptions: generateRangeNumber(4),
                editable: true,
            },
            {
                field: 'qtde',
                headerName: 'Quantidade de entregas',
                width: 180,
                sortable: false,
                disableReorder: true,
                type: 'number',
                disableColumnMenu: true,
                renderCell: (params) => <DeliveriesListIncrement params={params} />
            },
            {
                field: 'entregador',
                headerName: 'Entregador',
                width: 180,
                disableReorder: true,
                renderCell: (params) => {
                    if (params.value === null) {
                        return (
                            <Box
                                sx={{
                                    display: 'flex',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                }}
                            >
                                <Typography
                                    variant="body2"
                                    color='error'
                                    textTransform={'uppercase'}
                                >
                                    Aguardando...
                                </Typography>
                            </Box>
                        );
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field: 'whatsapp',
                headerName: 'WhatsApp do entregador',
                width: 180,
                sortable: false,
                disableReorder: true,
                disableColumnMenu: true,
            },
            {
                field: 'actions',
                headerName: 'Ações',
                type: 'actions',
                width: 120,
                renderCell: (params) => <ActionsDeliveries {...{ params, rowId, setRowId, handleListRefresh }} />,
            }
        ], [rowId]);
```

My DataGrid component:

```
<DataGrid
                rows={dataRow}
                columns={columns}
                loading={loading}
                getRowId={row => row.id}
                sx={{
                    [`& .${gridClasses.row}`]: {
                        bgcolor: (theme: any) =>
                            theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? theme.palette.background.paper : theme.palette.background.paper,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                    },
                }}
                getRowSpacing={(params) => ({
                    top: params.isFirstVisible ? 0 : 1,
                    bottom: params.isLastVisible ? 0 : 1,
                })}
                onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
                rowHeight={40}
                rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 15, 25]}
                pageSize={pageSize}
                hideFooter={deliveries?.length < 5}
                onRowClick={(params) => handleRowClick(params)}
                experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
            />
```

In the Qty column I would like to render two buttons to increment and decrement the row value.

Would you have any examples? I looked in the documentation and didn't find anything that could help me.